# How can I use a loop?

Tags: loops, neural-network, perceptron

I'm coding a multiplayer perceptron where I have calculated the sigmoids individually but would like to use a loop instead. How can I implement this into a loop? This is my working code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    //Initial weights    w1    w2   w3   w4   w5  w6     w7   w8
    double weights[] = {-0.1, 0.4,-0.2,-0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.3, -0.2};

    //number of inputs
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 0;

    //out
    double target = 0;

    double sum = 0;

    double Sigmoid1;
    double Sigmoid2;
    double Sigmoid3;

    int i = 0;

    while(i< weights.length){

        Sigmoid1 = (x1 * weights[i] );
                Sigmoid1 = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-Sigmoid1));

            Sigmoid2 = (x2 * weights[i] );
                Sigmoid2 = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-Sigmoid2));

            Sigmoid3 = (x1 * weights[2]) + (x2 * weights[4]);
                Sigmoid3 = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-Sigmoid3));



                 System.out.println("Sigmoid1 is: " + Sigmoid1);
                 System.out.println("Sigmoid2 is: " + Sigmoid2);
                 System.out.println("Sigmoid3 is: " + Sigmoid3);

                 break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Refactor out the duplication -- make an array of Sigmoid values and loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of doubles to hold the sigmoid values and weights for each layer. For instance:

```
double x = {1,0};

int layer1_input_size = 2; // number of inputs to network
int layer2_input_size = 2; // number of inputs to final layer

int layer1_output_size = 2; // number of outputs to first layer (must match inputs to next layer)
int layer2_output_size = 1; // number of outputs of network

// Initialize arrays to hold the values of outputs and weights for each layer
double sigmoid_layer1[] = new double[layer1_output_size];
double sigmoid_layer2[] = new double[layer2_output_size]
double weights_layer1[] = new double[layer1_input_size];
double weights_layer2[] = new double[layer2_input_size];

// iterate over each neuron in layer1
for(int j = 0; j < sigmoid_layer1.length; j++){
    double sum = 0; // sum of weights * inputs (also known as dot product)
    for(int i = 0; i < weights_layer1.length; i++){
        sum += (x[j] * weights_layer1[i]; // for every weight, multiply by corresponding input to layer
    }
    sigmoid_layer1[j] = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-sum); // sigmoid activation
}
for(int j = 0; j < sigmoid_layer2.length; j++){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < weights_layer2.length; i++){
        sum += (sigmoid_layer1[j] * weights_layer2[i]; // same as before, only now the inputs to this layer are the outputs from the previous layer
    }
    sigmoid_layer2[j] = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-sum);
}
```

The same type of abstraction could be used to allow for a dynamic number of layers as well.

Maybe a little background to explain my answer further:
In a neural network or a MultiLayer Perceptron, there are multiple sets (or layers) of computational units (neurons). Each of the neurons in one layer are connected to every neuron in the next layer (at least in the simplest case).The inputs to a layer, are the outputs of the layer before it, and the inputs to the first layer are the inputs to your network.

In your case (as I understand it):
Your inputs are in the x array. So x[0] = 1 is the first input, and x[1] = 0 is the second.
Your first layer consists of sigmoid1 and sigmoid2. I combined these and held the *outputs* of the activation functions in the array sigmoid_layer1.
Your second layer consists of sigmoid3. The inputs to sigmoid3 are the outputs of sigmoid1 and sigmoid2. The output of sigmoid3 (held in sigmoid_layer2) is the output of your network.
The number of weights in the network are determined by the number of inputs to each neuron. For instance: in layer 1 there are two inputs (x[0] and x[1]) and there are two neurons (sigmoid1 and sigmoid2). This means you will need 4 weights where weights_layer1[0] and weights_layer1[1] are the weights for the first neuron, and weights_layer1[2] and weights_layer1[3] are the weights for the second neuron.

This means that your overall network uses 6 weights. 4 in the first layer, and 2 in the second. To initialize these weights manually (as you are doing) it could be done as so:

```
double weights_layer1[] = {-0.1, 0.4, -0.2, -0.3};
double weights_layer2[] = {-0.2, 0.4};
```

Please note that there is no flexibility to the number of weights you initialize. If you go with this architecture (2 neurons in the first layer and 1 neuron in the second) then you can only have exactly 4 weights in the first array, and 2 weights in the second.

Comment: How would I input the weights and print the result?For example, Sigmoid1 is = 0.2, Sigmoid2 is = 0.5

Comment: Traditionally in a neural network the weights are randomly generated usually between [-1, 1] (although new research suggests other methods, this should work fine for now). However to keep it in the style of your current implementation you could use `double weights_layer1[] = {.2, .3, .4, .5}` and `double weights_layer2[] = {.6, .7}` Then printing would just loop over the layer functions. `for(int i = 0; i < sigmoid_layer1.length; i++) System.out.println(sigmoid_layer1[i]);` and do so for every layer.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `sigmoid_layer1`, `weights_layer1`, `layer1_output_size` is this the same as my implementation that I used for: `int x1 = 1;`, `double Sigmoid1;`

Comment: Those three are variables that I created in my implementation to assist with abstracting your code so that you could use a loop. `sigmoid_layer1` is a collection of the outputs in the first layer of your neural network `weights_layer1` are the weights for each neuron in that the first layer, and `layer1_output_size` is the number of outputs that the first layer has. These outputs are what will then be fed into the input of the second layer. If you had a third layer, then the outputs from the second layer would then be fed into the third, and so on.

Comment: I'm really stuck here, how do I run the code with my initial weight `//Initial weights    w1    w2   w3   w4   w5  w6     w7   w8
    double weights[] = {-0.1, 0.4,-0.2,-0.3, -0.2, 0.4, 0.3, -0.2};` as you suggested do I plug these in `double weights_layer1[] = {-0.1, 0.4, -0.2, -0.3...}` my number of inputs `//number of inputs
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 0;`

Comment: Assuming I am understanding what you are trying to do, you would initialize your weights for layer 1 as such: `double weights_layer1[] = {-.1, .4, -.2, -.3}` and your weights for layer 2: `double weights_layer2[] = {-.2, .4};` Although I must admit, I cannot tell for certain what architecture your network is based on your code, so I am not entirely certain what your weights are representing. I assume that x1 and x2 are inputs to the network? Also how do you have 8 weights for 3 neurons that are doing 1, 1, and 2 computations respectively. I count 4 weights being used in your implementation.

Comment: for sigmoid2 it works but sigmoid1 just displays the same input -0.3

Answer (score 0):

within the while loop I would probably do

```
double sigmoidInit[3] = { x1 * weights[i], 
    x2 * weights[i], 
    (x1 * weights[2]) + (x2 * weights[4])};
  for (int j = 0; j < sigmoidInit.length; j++) {
    double sigmoid = /* math on sigmoidInit */;
    / * your print statements */
  }
```

}